# eclipse cdt plugin: How to programmability apply c code formatter

Tags: eclipse-plugin, format, eclipse-cdt, preferences

I'm writing a plugin for eclipse(Kepler) CDT on windows 8.1.
My plugin extends eclipse and enables the user to create a project with a specific configurations.
I want all my plugin projects to be with the same c code format. So in my plugin code, when creating the project files and configuration, I added the following code in order to add the wanted format:

```java
ProjectScope scope = new ProjectScope(project);
IEclipsePreferences ref = scope.getNode("org.eclipse.cdt.core");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.lineSplit", "100");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_parameters_in_method_declaration", "18");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block", "next_line");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_method_declaration", "next_line");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char", "space");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation", "18");
ref.put("org.eclipse.cdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_constructor_initializer_list", "16");
ref.flush();
```

This code really does its job and configures the format as I want, but the generated format exists only in the project properties, and not being applied yet. If I want to apply the format and cause the files to show with this format, I have to click on *apply* button, or to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Do you know about any way to apply the format programmability, though each project will be generated with its auto-generated files that are formatted already?

Comment: Have you looked at the command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is bound to? Can you run that command on the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. thanks @Bananewizen for helping!
I found that the command id behind the ctrl+shift+f is: `ICEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT`
and I succeeded to run the command programmability, but I had to handle the file loading in order to format its code. so I implemented IPartListener, and in partOpened function, I wrote:

```
@Override
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {
    try {
        IFile file = (IFile) part.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
            final String cmdName = ICEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT;
            IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
            try {
                handlerService.executeCommand(cmdName, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Now the handle is found and it works well!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the command ID using either the Eclipse menu spy (Alt-Shift-F2) or by looking up the key binding for the formatter in the key preferences or by importing the cdt.ui plugin as source plugin into your workbench.

When you have the command ID, then you can [execute it programmatically](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters) using the command service.

Comment: first of all - thanks! I found the command id as ICEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT. but now, I cannot execute this command programmability, since when i'm using handlerService.executeCommand() function,  i'm getting this exception: "There is no handler to execute for command ". any idea?

Comment: Not really, as I've only done this with very basic commands. I assume that the plugin containing the actual _handler_ for the command is not loaded in your runtime. But that seems not really likely, as you probably depend on several of the CDT plugins, I guess. You could still try to get the command from the CommandService (not HandlerService) and execute it yourself, but that seems not to be the recommended way.